# Java 8 (Stream) - Soma agrupada

Tags: java, java-8, stream

Bom dia.

Eu tenho a seguinte função abaixo:

```java
private List<Object[]> calcularTotal(List<Object[]> lista, int chave, int valor){
    return lista.stream()
            .map(l -> new Object[] {l[chave], l[valor]})
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(o -> o[0], Collectors.summingDouble(v -> ((BigDecimal) v[1]).doubleValue())))
            .entrySet()
            .stream()
            .map(o -> new Object[] {o.getKey(), o.getValue()})
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Lista : `{[45, 100], [45, 200], [50, 30]}`

Resultado da função: `{[45, 300], [50, 30]}`

Acumulando um valor eu consegui fazer, mas não tenho ideia de como fazer acumulando mais um valor.

Por exemplo:

Lista : `{[45, 100, 200], [45, 200, 400], [50, 30, 60]}`

Resultado desejado: `{[45, 300, 600], [50, 30, 60]}`

Em ambos exemplos, a primeira posição é a chave por onde vai agrupar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui resolver o problema.

Mesmo assim, agradeço pela ajuda.

Como ficou a função:

```
public static List<Object[]> calcularTotal(List<Object[]> lista, int chave, int... valores){
    List<Map<Object, Double>> maps = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i : valores)
        maps.add(lista.stream()
                      .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(o -> o[chave], Collectors.summingDouble(v -> ((BigDecimal) ((Object[]) v)[i]).doubleValue()))));

    List<Object[]> list = new ArrayList<>();

    maps.get(0).keySet().stream().sorted().forEach(o -> {
        List<Object> l = new ArrayList<>();
        l.add(o);
        maps.forEach(m -> l.add(m.get(o)));

        list.add(l.toArray());
    });

    return list;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Consegui, mas deu bastante trabalho:

```java
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

/**
 * @author Victor
 */
public class StreamArray {

    // Obtido daqui: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15497288/540552
    public static Object[][] transposeMatrix(Object[][] m) {
        Object[][] temp = new Object[m[0].length][m.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < m[0].length; j++) {
                temp[j][i] = m[i][j];
            }
        }
        return temp;
    }

    // Converte o List<List<Object>> em Object[][], faz a transposição, e converte de volta em List<List<Object>>.
    public static List<List<Object>> transpose(List<List<Object>> m) {
        Object[][] a = m.stream().map(List::toArray).collect(Collectors.toList()).toArray(new Object[][] {});
        Object[][] b = transposeMatrix(a);
        return Arrays.asList(b).stream().map(Arrays::asList).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    public static List<Object> join(List<List<Object>> lists) {
        // Recebemos um List<List<Object>> aonde o List interno é um conjunto de chaves e valores.
        // O List externo é uma lista de conjuntos de chaves e valores.
        return transpose(lists)
                .stream()

                // Agora temos um Stream<List<Object>> diferente.
                // O List interno é um conjunto de elementos em uma mesma posição.
                // O Stream externo é uma lista de conjuntos de elementos em uma mesma posição.

                // Em cada List interno, soma todos os valores. O resultado é um Stream<Object>, aonde cada Object é
                // a soma dos valores em uma dada posição.
                .map(x -> x.stream().collect(Collectors.summingDouble(v -> ((BigDecimal) v).doubleValue())))

                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    private static Stream<List<Object>> calcularTotal2(Stream<List<Object>> st, int chave) {
        return st
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(o -> o.get(chave), Collectors.toList())) // Agora temos um Map<Object, List<List<Object>>>
                .entrySet() // Temos agora um Collection<Map.Entry<Object, List<List<Object>>>>
                .stream()

                // Temos agora um Stream<Map.Entry<Object, List<List<Object>>>>.
                // A lista interna equivale a um array contendo a chave e os valores.
                // A lista intermediária é um conjunto de listas representando chaves e valores tal que todas tem a mesma chave.
                // O entry é a relação de chaves para listas intermediárias.
                // O stream externo é o conjunto total.

                .map(e -> {
                    List<Object> in = StreamArray.join(e.getValue()); // Junta as listas intermediárias.
                    in.set(chave, e.getKey()); // Coloca a chave de volta.
                    return in;
                });
    }

    private static List<Object[]> calcularTotal(List<Object[]> lista, int chave) {
        return calcularTotal2(lista.stream().map(Arrays::asList), chave)
                .map(x -> x.toArray(new Object[x.size()]))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        // Cria alguns valores BigDecimal para colocar no List<Object[]>
        BigDecimal BD_30 = BigDecimal.valueOf(30);
        BigDecimal BD_45 = BigDecimal.valueOf(45);
        BigDecimal BD_50 = BigDecimal.valueOf(50);
        BigDecimal BD_60 = BigDecimal.valueOf(60);
        BigDecimal BD_100 = BigDecimal.valueOf(100);
        BigDecimal BD_200 = BigDecimal.valueOf(200);
        BigDecimal BD_400 = BigDecimal.valueOf(400);

        // Vamos calcular com isso. A posição 0 de cada array é a chave.
        List<Object[]> a = Arrays.asList(
                new Object[] {BD_45, BD_100, BD_200},
                new Object[] {BD_45, BD_200, BD_400},
                new Object[] {BD_50, BD_30, BD_60});

        // Faz a mágica.
        List<List<Object>> b = calcularTotal(a, 0) // Faz a mágica.
                .stream()
                .map(Arrays::asList) // Transforma os arrays internos em listas, assim o System.out imprime eles de uma forma legal.
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        System.out.println(b);
    }
}
```

Eis a saída:

```
[[45, 300.0, 600.0], [50, 30.0, 60.0]]
```

Primeiramente, usei o código para fazer a transposição de matrizes daqui: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15497288/540552

O motivo de precisar fazê-lo é que quando temos uma lista de listas, para obter uma lista de somas, basta aplicar para cada elemento da lista externa algo que some todos os elementos de uma lista. Isso é bem mais fácil do que criar uma lista aonde cada elemento é uma posição que contém a soma dos elementos da lista interna naquela mesma posição.

Tendo o código para transpor uma matriz, para aplicá-lo a uma lista de listas, preciso primeiro convertê-la em matriz, transpor, e depois converter de volta em lista de listas.

No código, você deve perceber que fiz o método `calcularTotal2` trabalhar com `Stream<List<Object>>` ao invés de `Stream<Object[]>` ou `List<Object[]>`. O motivo disso é que misturar arrays com streams é horrível e o código ficaria bem mais complicado se eu não fizesse isso. O método `calcularTotal` apenas converte o `List<Object[]>` em um `Stream<List<Object>>` e converte o `Stream<List<Object>>` resultante em `List<Object[]>`

Considerações acerca disso:

- Com certeza é possível transpor a lista de listas sem precisar converter em matriz e converter de volta depois, mas isso é um tanto trabalhoso porque a matriz já é criada com todas as posições necessárias, enquanto que na lista de listas, tanto a lista externa quanto as internas são criadas vazias e as não dá para simplesmente "setar" um elemento em uma posição sem que esta posição exista antes.
- No final eu estou convertendo de array para lista no `calcularTotal` convertendo de novo em array no `transpose`, convertendo de volta para lista no `transpose` e convertendo novamente para array no `calcularTotal`. Obviamente que eu poderia não fazer todas estas conversões e trabalhar com arrays do começo ao fim, mas novamente repito que arrays e streams não combinam.
- Por fim, usar arrays diretamente deste jeito, normalmente é um sinal de que há algum problema na orientação a objetos, ainda mais se o array é do tipo `Object`. O que o array representa talvez deveria ser uma classe específica com métodos específicos, ainda mais considerando que uma das posições dele tem um significado especial (a chave). Neste caso, é possível que o algoritmo/programa saia de uma forma bem mais elegante usando mais orientação a objetos e menos listas, maps e arrays.
- `Stream`s, como qualquer outra ferramenta do java não são balas de pratas e podem ser usadas e abusadas de forma incorreta como qualquer outra coisa. Ou seja, às vezes (mas nem sempre, obviamente) é mais fácil e mais prático usar o velho `for` de sempre e deixar os `Stream`s de lado. Também é possível usar uma estratégia híbrida aonde há um `Stream` na parte externa e um `for` na interna ou vice-versa, ou algo parecido com isso.

Comment: +1 Pelo esforço. Provavelmente deve ter levado tempo para criar tudo isso. :)

Answer (score 2):

Apresento uma solução por `map` e `reduce`.

## Map

Dada a entrada crua `List<Object[]> lista`, você só está interessado nas colunas cujos índices estejam em `int... valores`. Você também quer separar o valor de determinado índice como chave.

## Reduce

Aqui temos duas operações dentro do pipeline:

1. Agrupar pela chave.
2. Somar todos os valores selecionados, coluna a coluna.

---

Você já descobriu o `Collectors.groupingBy` que faz a primeira redução do pipeline, agora precisamos escrever o passo do `map` e o passo da soma na redução. Para tanto vou desenvolver uma classe auxiliar representando nossa "tabela":

```
public class Holder {

    /**
     * Segundo passo da redução.
     * @return soma colunas selecionadas
     */
    public static Object[] combine(Object[] first, Object[] second) {
        return IntStream.range(0, first.length).mapToObj(i -> {
            final BigDecimal x = (BigDecimal) first[i];
            final BigDecimal y = (BigDecimal) second[i];
            return x.add(y);
        }).toArray();
    }

    final BigDecimal key;
    final Object[] selectedValues;

    /**
     * Passo do mapeamento.
     *
     * @param values entradas cruas
     * @param keyIndex indice da chave
     * @param valueIndexes indices selecionados
     */
    public Holder(Object[] values, int keyIndex, int... valueIndexes) {
        this.key = (BigDecimal) values[keyIndex];
        this.selectedValues = Arrays
                .stream(valueIndexes)
                .mapToObj(i -> values[i])
                .toArray();
    }

    /**
     * Elemento neutro para a redução.
     * @param size quantidade de colunas no elemento neutro
     */
    public Holder(int size) {
        this.key = null;
        this.selectedValues = new Object[size];
        Arrays.fill(selectedValues, BigDecimal.ZERO);
    }

    public Object[] getSelectedValues() {
        return selectedValues;
    }

    public BigDecimal getKey() {
        return key;
    }
}
```

Uma vez que você tenha essa estrutura o processamento é bem direto:

```
public static Map<BigDecimal, Object[]> calcularTotal(List<Object[]> lista, int chave, 
                                                      int... valores) {
    final Map<BigDecimal, Object[]> results = lista
            .stream()
            .map(o -> new Holder(o,chave, valores))
            .collect(
                    Collectors.groupingBy(
                            Holder::getKey,
                            Collectors.reducing(
                                    new Holder(valores.length).getSelectedValues(),
                                    Holder::getSelectedValues,
                                    Holder::combine)));
    return results;
}
```

Não vejo motivo para mapear um `Map<BigDecimal, Object[]>` novamente para uma `List<Object[]>`, porém, caso você realmente necessite, é trivial fazer a conversão em cima do `entrySet` conforme sua própria resposta.

---

[**Gist com código fonte completo**](https://gist.github.com/aaccioly/9d62f468a515ae1530de)